Error Starting Kafka on macOS: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.kafka.coordinator.group.Group.GroupType.CLASS
I recently installed Kafka on macOS using Homebrew with the following commands:
brew install kafka
After installation, I attempted to start the Kafka server using the command:
/opt/homebrew/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start /opt/homebrew/etc/kafka/server.properties
However, I encountered the following error:
[2024-07-16 10:40:29,663] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2024-07-16 10:40:29,678] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.kafka.coordinator.group.Group.GroupType.CLASSIC
    at java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:293)
    at org.apache.kafka.coordinator.group.Group$GroupType.valueOf(Group.java:29)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.$anonfun$groupCoordinatorRebalanceProtocols$2(KafkaConfig.scala:2020)
    at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.map(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:100)
    at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.map$(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:87)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.map(ArrayBuffer.scala:43)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:2020)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1639)
    at kafka.Kafka$.buildServer(Kafka.scala:71)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:90)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)

It appears that there is an issue with an enum constant in the org.apache.kafka.coordinator.group.Group.GroupType class.
What might be causing this error and how to resolve it?
kafka: stable 3.7.1 (bottled)

The issue is likely related to Kafka detecting the local language settings during startup. I encountered a similar problem with Kafka 3.8.0 on Windows and resolved it using the following steps. You might be able to apply a similar approach on macOS:
I needed to edit the .bin/windows/kafka-server-start.bat file using Notepad and add the following line:
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US"

I recommend placing this line just above the following lines:
"%~dp0kafka-run-class.bat" kafka.Kafka %*
EndLocal

To make sure for changing it I opened my environment variables and added a new environment variable:

Variable name: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
Variable value: -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US

After making these changes, closed and reopened the Command Prompt as an administrator, then navigated to the directory containing the Kafka files.
Then without this error, I was able to run Kafka's server.
This change gives a warning on the console, but the application works after all.

Thank you for the answer. My problem was solved but I don't know how :)

The issue occurs due to locale differences, where the Turkish uppercase "İ" causes a mismatch in the expected value. Adding the following lines to the Kafka batch file resolves the problem by enforcing the English locale:
rem Java options for locale settings
IF ["%JAVA_OPTS%"] EQU [""] (
    set JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US
    set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US
)

This ensures Kafka processes the configuration values correctly, avoiding locale-specific issues.
